# Tyring to add followers to microposts, error: 'missing parameter microposts'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been trying to add followers to microposts with the following controller:

microposts_controller.rb :

```
def follow
  @user = current_user
  set_micropost
  if @micropost.user_id != current_user.id
    @micropost.followed += 1
    @micropost.save
  end
end
```

The thing is there is always a 'missing parameter' error 'microposts'.  Meaning I am not passing a `@micropost` to the controller.  The 
    `<%= link_to 'Follow' uses micropost_new_path(micropost), method: 'follow' %>`

So I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  Defined the appropriate routes (the error states it is a `microposts#create` error, and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's likely a few things that aren't quite right here, but the first one that stands out is that it looks like you've misunderstood what the `method` option for `link_to` is for. Here, "method" doesn't mean the name of the method your controller, it means the *HTTP method* to use for the request (such as POST, PUT, DELETE and and so on.) So it's likely this link is unintentionally calling the `create` action instead of the `follow` action.

For adding additional actions take a look at the section in the routing guide on [Adding More RESTful Actions](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions)

---

As a brief example for creating a method to add followers:

If you have an micropost defined as a resource in your routes:

```
resources :microposts
```

and would like a new action (such as "follow") that applies to individual microposts you can update your resource to be:

```
resources :microposts do
  post 'follow', on: :member
end
```

You can then add a `follow` method in your `microposts_controller.rb`, similar how you've done already. After editing your routes this will also provide a `follow_micropost_path` helper function that can be used to link to this action.

Comment: great thanks, how would i create a new method for adding followers?

Comment: Sorry about the wonky code, I was just really trying to fix the parameters issue, and had also put an extra 'wonky' route generated by rails for whatever reason, thanks for yhour help!